# comparing name property on objects in two separate arrays and creating a new filtered array in React

Tags: reactjs, filter, use-effect, use-state

in my react component I have an array called providerServices and an array called userServices. Both hold multiple objects with a name property.
on page load I need a filtered version of providerServices that does not include any objects with the same name property as the objects in userServices.

```
  useEffect(() => {
    userServices.map((us) => {
      setFilteredServices(providerServices.filter((service) => service.name !== us.name))
    })
  }, [])
```

my code above is only removing the first obj that matches instead of all that match. Some help or guidance would be much appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to filter out from `providerServices` every element that `.find` locates on `userServices`

```js
providerServices.filter(function(providerServicesObj) {
  return !userServices.find(function(userServicesObj) {
    return providerServicesObj.name === userServicesObj.name
  })
})
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work fine, one-liner solutions in ES6:

```
useEffect(() => {
    const filteredServices = providerServices.filter(({ name: providerServicesName }) => 
        !userServices.some(({ name: userServicesName }) => userServicesName === 
        providerServicesName));
    setFilteredServices(filteredServices);
  }, [])
```